# Contar caracteres dentro de una cadena en Python

Tags: python

Tengo una pequeña función que cuenta ocurrencia de caracteres en una cadena. me funciona en algunos sitios, pero no en otros. Concretamente en Jupyter no va bien y no sé la razón.
Gracias.

```
def char_frequency(str1):
dict = {}
for n in str1:
    keys = dict.keys()
if n in keys:
     dict[n] += 1
else:
    dict[n] = 1
return dict
```

Comment: Por favor, corrige la indentación, en python es muy importante para analizar tu código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supongo que solo quieres saber la cantidad de caracteres que hay en la cadena y almacenarlos en un diccionario donde la clave sea el carácter y el valor sea el número de veces que aparece:

```
def char_frequency(str1):
    res = dict()
    for caracter in str1:
        if caracter in res.keys():
            res[caracter] = res[caracter] + 1
        else:
            res[caracter] = 1
    return res
```

Otra opción más elegante sería utilizar la librería **collections**

```
from collections import Counter
p = "Hola me llamo Pepe"
print(Counter(p))
```

Esto devuelve:

```
Counter({'l': 3, ' ': 3, 'e': 3, 'o': 2, 'a': 2, 'm': 2, 'H': 1, 'P': 1, 'p': 1})
```

Comment: muchas gracias por las respuestas. El problema estaba en la indentación. conocía la la segunda opción con Counter, pero tenía que hacerlo de esta forma en este ejemplo concreto.

Comment: Perfecto, pues ya sabes la importancia de la indentación :)